# MySQL view with a function to create an input variable

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create an SQL view in MySQL that takes an input variable say as a function argument? I have found this caption from the MySQL web site but am not sure how to use it as I am quite new to SQL functions.  When I run this in the MySQL command prompt ,it gives me errors. Also I am not sure if this is even what I am looking for?

```
create function book_subject
returns varchar(64) as
return @book_subject;

create view thematical_books as
select title, author
from books
where subject = book_subject();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting errors because the `CREATE FUNCTION` syntax is incorrect (gotta love those MySQL manual user comments!).  The correct syntax for creating this function is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION book_subject()
RETURNS VARCHAR(64)
RETURN @subject;
```

The `CREATE VIEW` syntax is correct.

In order to use the view, you'll need to set the variable `@book_subject` before you select from the view:

```
SET @book_subject = 'Epic Poems';
```

Then when you do a:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   thematical_books;
```

It will return the title and author of all of the books that have a subject of 'Epic Poems'

This is a trick to get around the restriction of MySQL views that "The SELECT statement [of the view] cannot refer to system or user variables."  You use a function that just returns the variable, and that function gets called each time the view is used.

Comment: what is the scope of the @book_subject variable?

Answer (score 1):

This is about as close as you are likely to get.  There isn't an official way to get any arguments passed into a view (because how do you supply the argument when the view is referenced in the FROM clause).  Using a session global variable and a function as shown is about the only way to achieve the effect.  It is sneaky and bug-prone - not good attributes for clean maintainable code.